# Undefined Error on "comment.user.name" - Laravel and VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2, vuex

I build a comment system with Laravel 5, VueJS 2 and Vuex. I can retrieve all comments and comment.user.username works fine when I load page.
But when I post a new Comment I get this error in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: _vm.comment.user is undefined"
```

**When I replace comment.user.name with comment.user_id, and I post, Its works**. comment.created_at works too. **comment.user.name display user name when I reload page**. **But When I Post, I get Undefined Error**

Comment and User Model relationship are defined.
Please, How can I resolve this error?

Comment: show your code and table fields

Comment: this is vue code, see below

Comment: First of all remove you answer, edit your question and put details there.
second you have not any username field in your table that's why you are getting error.

Comment: Relationship are defined in Model. In Json I retrieve Comment and User associated details. When I load Comment, comment.user.name works. There is not user name field in comment table because, its a relation

Answer (score 0):

My comment table
[image]

My Comments.vue

```
<template>

<div class="ui comments innerAllWithoutTop">
    <div class="ui inverted active dimmer" v-if="loading">
        <div class="ui text loader">Chargement des commentaires...</div>
    </div>
  <h4 class="ui dividing header">Les commentaires</h4>
  <comment :comment="comment" v-for="comment in comments" :key="id"></comment>
  <comment-form :id="id" :model="model"></comment-form>
</div>

</template>
<script type="text/babel">
import axios from 'axios'
import Comment from './comments/Comment.vue'
import CommentForm from './comments/Form.vue'
import store from '../store/Store'


export default {
  data () {
    return {
        loading: true,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    comments: {
        get: function () {
            return store.state.comments
        },
        set: function (comments) {
            store.commit('ADD_COMMENTS', comments)
        }
    }
  },
  components: { Comment, CommentForm },
  props: {
    id: Number,
    model: String
  },
  methods: {
    getComments () {
      axios.get('/comments', {params: {
        type: this.model, id: this.id
      }}).then((response) => {
        this.comments = response.data
      }).then(() => {
        this.loading = false
      });
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getComments();
  }
}
</script>
```

My comment.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="comment">
      <a class="avatar">
        <img :src="comment.user.profile.photo">
      </a>
      <div class="content">
        <a class="author">{{ comment.user.username }}</a>
        <div class="metadata">
          <span class="date">{{ comment.created_at }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          {{ comment.content }}
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <a class="reply">Répondre</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comments" v-if="comment.reply == 0">
      <comment :comment="reply" v-for="reply in comment.replies" :key="reply.id"></comment>
      <!--<comment-form :model="comment.commentable_type" :id="comment.commentable_id" :reply="comment.id" v-if="comment.reply == 0"></comment-form>-->
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CommentForm from './Form.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'comment',
    components: { CommentForm },
    props: {
      comment: Object
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comments works, User name works but when I post comment I get Undefined comment.user in Console